How to integrate Jenkins with GitHub for automated C code testing using Ceedling and Unity?
I have integrated Jenkins with GitHub using Webhook Relay, triggered every time a developer tries to push their code. I used Webhook Relay because of the lack of a public IP, which prevented Git from seeing Jenkins installed on my PC.
I then attempted to create a Jenkins job to automate unit tests using Ceedling and Unity for my C language code. I tried both freestyle and pipeline jobs to run the command ceedling test:all, and it worked once in each case.
My main objective is to have Jenkins automatically start and run the test cases every time a developer pushes their code to Git. If there is a failed test case, it should prevent the code from being committed. Additionally, I want Jenkins to perform checks before a developer can merge a branch into the main branch.
When the Jenkins job runs, this is the output I get:
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/MNasser-iono/test_sum.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/MNasser-iono/test_sum.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.17.1'
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/MNasser-iono/test_sum.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 25ccdcaf01ff2422eb1b7e3a67858855410840b2 (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 25ccdcaf01ff2422eb1b7e3a67858855410840b2 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Update README_12.02.md"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 25ccdcaf01ff2422eb1b7e3a67858855410840b2 # timeout=10
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
[Pipeline] sh
+ ceedling test:all


Test 'test_sum_function.c'
--------------------------
Generating runner for test_sum_function.c...
Compiling test_sum_function_runner.c...
Linking test_sum_function.out...
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `build/test/out/c/test_sum_function.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `build/test/out/c/unity.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `build/test/out/c/sum_function.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `build/test/out/c/cmock.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
build/test/out/c/test_sum_function_runner.o: In function `resetTest':
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:36: undefined reference to `tearDown'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:40: undefined reference to `setUp'
build/test/out/c/test_sum_function_runner.o: In function `run_test':
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:51: undefined reference to `Unity'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:52: undefined reference to `Unity'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:57: undefined reference to `Unity'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:57: undefined reference to `Unity'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:58: undefined reference to `Unity'
build/test/out/c/test_sum_function_runner.o:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:58: more undefined references to `Unity' follow
build/test/out/c/test_sum_function_runner.o: In function `run_test':
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:63: undefined reference to `setUp'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:66: undefined reference to `Unity'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:68: undefined reference to `tearDown'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:73: undefined reference to `UnityConcludeTest'
build/test/out/c/test_sum_function_runner.o: In function `main':
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:79: undefined reference to `UnityBegin'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:80: undefined reference to `test_sum_function_NeedToImplement'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:81: undefined reference to `test_sum_negative_numbers'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:82: undefined reference to `test_sum_zero'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ceedling_pipeline/build/test/runners/test_sum_function_runner.c:84: undefined reference to `UnityEnd'
build/test/out/c/unity.o: In function `UnityPrintChar':
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:85: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:90: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:91: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:96: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:97: undefined reference to `_putchar'
build/test/out/c/unity.o:C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:102: more undefined references to `_putchar' follow
build/test/out/c/unity.o: In function `UnityPrintFloat':
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:362: undefined reference to `___isnanf'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:366: undefined reference to `___fpclassifyf'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:455: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:456: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:462: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:466: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:471: undefined reference to `_putchar'
build/test/out/c/unity.o:C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:482: more undefined references to `_putchar' follow
build/test/out/c/unity.o: In function `UnityFloatsWithin':
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:901: undefined reference to `___fpclassifyf'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:901: undefined reference to `___fpclassifyf'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:901: undefined reference to `___isnanf'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:901: undefined reference to `___isnanf'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:901: undefined reference to `___isnanf'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:901: undefined reference to `___fpclassifyf'
build/test/out/c/unity.o: In function `UnityAssertFloatSpecial':
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:988: undefined reference to `___fpclassifyf'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:992: undefined reference to `___fpclassifyf'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:997: undefined reference to `___isnanf'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1002: undefined reference to `___fpclassifyf'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1002: undefined reference to `___isnanf'
build/test/out/c/unity.o: In function `UnityFail':
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1766: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1786: undefined reference to `_putchar'
build/test/out/c/unity.o: In function `UnityIgnore':
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1803: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1804: undefined reference to `_putchar'
build/test/out/c/unity.o: In function `UnityMessage':
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1817: undefined reference to `_putchar'
build/test/out/c/unity.o:C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1818: more undefined references to `_putchar' follow
build/test/out/c/unity.o: In function `UnityDefaultTestRun':
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1834: undefined reference to `__setjmp'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1839: undefined reference to `__setjmp'
build/test/out/c/unity.o: In function `UnityEnd':
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1873: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1875: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1882: undefined reference to `_putchar'
C:/Users/PC/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.c:1894: undefined reference to `_putchar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: Shell command failed.
> Shell executed command:
'gcc "build/test/out/c/test_sum_function_runner.o" "build/test/out/c/test_sum_function.o" "build/test/out/c/unity.o" "build/test/out/c/sum_function.o" "build/test/out/c/cmock.o" -o "build/test/out/test_sum_function.out"'
> And exited with status: [1].


NOTICE: If the linker reports missing symbols, the following may be to blame:
  1. Test lacks #include statements corresponding to needed source files.
  2. Project search paths do not contain source files corresponding to #include statements in the test.
  3. Test does not #include needed mocks.

rake aborted!

/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/generator.rb:151:in `rescue in generate_executable_file'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/generator.rb:136:in `generate_executable_file'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/rules_tests.rake:39:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/task_invoker.rb:107:in `invoke_test_results'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/test_invoker.rb:125:in `block in setup_and_invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/test_invoker.rb:51:in `setup_and_invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/tasks_tests.rake:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/bin/ceedling:345:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/bin/ceedling:332:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/ceedling:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/ceedling:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ShellExecutionException: ShellExecutionException
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/tool_executor.rb:88:in `exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/generator.rb:136:in `generate_executable_file'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/rules_tests.rake:39:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/task_invoker.rb:107:in `invoke_test_results'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/test_invoker.rb:125:in `block in setup_and_invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/test_invoker.rb:51:in `setup_and_invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/tasks_tests.rake:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/bin/ceedling:345:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/bin/ceedling:332:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/ceedling:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/ceedling:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => build/test/results/test_sum_function.pass => build/test/out/test_sum_function.out
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
ERROR: Ceedling Failed
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
Finished: FAILURE

And this is the pipeline script I used to test Ceedling:
''' groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/MNasser-iono/test_sum.git']]])
                sh 'ceedling test:all'
            }
        }
    }
}
'''




